# Reading settings bundle first time not returning correct values

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, settings.bundle

I have some code where I am reading a switch value from my settings bundle however on some instances it reads the wrong value.

This is what my code looks like, it's in my app delegate **applicationDidBecomeActive**

```
NSUserDefaults *settings = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *branchString = [settings objectForKey:@"signout"];

BOOL userSignOut = [[settings objectForKey:@"signout"] boolValue];
NSLog(userSignOut ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

What happens is when the app first loads I receive **NO** then when I switch to settings and turn my switch over to YES, when I log back in I still get **NO** however if I then switch between settings and my app again with out touch the switch in settings that's when I get **YES** even though it should have happened a step earlier.

Comment: have you called [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] after you set it?

Comment: when you say after i set it, do you mean after the first line of code I have shown in my question?

Comment: No, after you set it to YES by calling [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"signout"]

Comment: @JackWu He's talking about the value being changed by the Settings app. There is no relevant call to `setObject:forKey:`.

Comment: yea that worked.. thanks for that. i dont understand why it wouldnt just have the correct values when first read. so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this when setting the value?

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:(id) forKey:(NSString *)];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: This isn't related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification as observer.